# The expected output 'Test Passed' is not returned for the Java 8 Sample

Tags: java, implementation

I am quite new to Java 8 and I am trying to create a sample program using lambda expressions

I want to print 'Test Passed' when the driver.getTitle() method returns "Home Page - Safe2Pay Application".

I have implemented two different approaches. Approach 1 is the normal Java workflow, which prints the output 'Test Passed' in the console properly.
But Approach 2, using Java 8 does not work.

```
String expectedTitle = "Home Page - Safe2Pay Application";
String actualTitle = "";

//Approach 1
actualTitle = driver.getTitle();

if (actualTitle.contentEquals(expectedTitle)) {
    System.out.println("Test Passed");
} else {
    System.out.println("Test Failed");
}

//Approach 2
//Java 8 execution
GetTitle m = () -> {
    if (driver.getTitle().contentEquals(expectedTitle))
        System.out.println("Test Passed");
    else
        System.out.println("Test Failed");
};
```

Comment: Approach 2 is only a function definition, but you are not executing it.

Comment: What is `GetTitle`?

Comment: When you use a lambda, you're basically saving a method to be called later.  The method would be called usually with another method like `apply()` or `run()` or something, depending on the type in which you've stored the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare a GetTitle interface and call the method inside that interface.

```
public class Driver {
   static String expectedTitle = "Home Page - Safe2Pay Application";
   static String actualTitle = "";
   public static void main(String args[]){

      Driver driver = new Driver();

      //Approach 1
      actualTitle = getTitle();

      if (actualTitle.contentEquals(expectedTitle)) {
        System.out.println("Test Passed");
      } else {
        System.out.println("Test Failed");
      }

      //Approach 2
      //Java 8 execution
      GetTitle m = (Driver dr) -> {
        if (Driver.getTitle().contentEquals(expectedTitle))
            System.out.println("Test Passed");
        else
            System.out.println("Test Failed");
      };

       m.operation(driver);

    }
    public static String getTitle(){
       return expectedTitle;
    }

   interface GetTitle {
      void operation(Driver driver);
   }
}
```

Interface can be inside the class or outside the class.

Answer (score 2):

After you created an instance, you still have to call the method of your custom functional interface. Since you didnt post your GetTitle class, ill give a small example of how it should work using another custom functional interface.

```
// the functional interface
@FunctionalInterface
public static interface Operator {
    public void operate();
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Operator o = () -> System.out.println("test"); //here you create a class instance of Operator.
    o.operate(); // this is how you call that method/functional interface.

    // this is a non-lambda example which works exactually the same, but may make things a bit more clear.

    //create new instance
    Operator o1 = new Operator() {
        @Override
        public void operate()
        {
            System.out.println("test");
        }
    };

    o1.operate(); //call the method.
}
```

I hope this gave you enough insight of how functional interfaces work.

Comment: It might help to fix the typos so that readers can run this themselves.  `FunctionalInterface` begins with upper-case `F`, and you misspelled `Operator` on line 2.

Comment: Thanks, will fix it. The typos when you work from a mobile device :D

Comment: Don't blame the devcie, I'm perefclty capalbe of making typos form any keybaord.